# Making IntelliJ aware of my custom field injection mechanism

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I wrote a simple `BeanPostProcessor` to get more familiar with how Spring works

```java
package org.example.demos.beanPostProcessor;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);
        Sage sage = context.getBean("sage", Sage.class);
        sage.sayWisdom();
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example.demos.beanPostProcessor;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class Config {
}
```

```java
package org.example.demos.beanPostProcessor;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Sage {
    @Wisdom
    private String wisdom; // "never assigned"

    public void sayWisdom() {
        String processedWisdom = process(wisdom);
        System.out.println(processedWisdom);
    }

    private String process(String wisdom) {
        String intro = getIntro();
        String wiserWisdom = makeItSoundWiser(wisdom);
        return intro + " " + wiserWisdom;
    }

    private String getIntro() {
        return "Sage says:";
    }

    private String makeItSoundWiser(String wisdom) {
        return wisdom.replaceAll("\\.(?=\\s|$)|(?<!\\.)(?=$)", "...");
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example.demos.beanPostProcessor;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleWisdomProvider implements WisdomProvider {
    private final String[] wisdoms = {
            "Tomorrow is often the busiest day of the week.",
            "I have always wanted to be somebody, but I see now I should have been more specific.",
            "Knowledge is like underwear. It is useful to have it, but not necessary to show it off.",
            "Go to Heaven for the climate, Hell for the company.",
            "Going to church doesn’t make you a Christian any more than going to a garage makes you an automobile."
    };

    @Override
    public String getWisdom() {
        int randomIndex = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(wisdoms.length);
        return wisdoms[randomIndex];
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example.demos.beanPostProcessor;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface Wisdom {
}
```

```java
package org.example.demos.beanPostProcessor;

import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Objects;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WisdomBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {
    private final WisdomProvider wisdomProvider;
    @Override
    public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        Field[] fields = bean.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            Wisdom wisdom = field.getAnnotation(Wisdom.class);
            if (Objects.nonNull(wisdom)) {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                ReflectionUtils.setField(field, bean, wisdomProvider.getWisdom());
                break;
            }
        }
        return bean;
    }
}
```

```java
package org.example.demos.beanPostProcessor;

public interface WisdomProvider {
    String getWisdom();
}
```

It works, but I wonder whether I can make IntelliJ aware of my initialization mechanism so that I don't get a warning

> Private field 'wisdom' is never assigned

Slapping `@SuppressWarnings` onto my `wisdom` field is ugly. I tried hiding it within the `@Wisdom` annotation, but it's apparently not really transitive so the warning is still present. Of course, I don't want to disable the warning altogether

What are my options?

Comment: Not unless you write a plugin/extension for Intellij.

Comment: @M.Deinum but how does IntelliJ know that `@Autowired` fields are initialized? I need something similar, I guess

Comment: That is due to the dedicated Spring Plugins which are programmed just for that cause, much like the CDI plugin is for CDI annotations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on the warning and select `Assume field annotated by @Wisdom as implicitly written` in the intention list that appears. Now any field annotated by `@Wisdom` will no longer be reported as not assigned.

This will add the annotation to the "Unused declaration" inspection's settings. You can remove it again, by going the settings of this inspection, selecting the Entry Points tab, and clicking the Annotations button. The annotation name will be in the bottom list of the dialog that appears.

[image: inspection settings visual guide]

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me more about that `Entry Points` tab? I can't find it

Comment: I have added a screen shot to guide the way.